# Adding additional fields to ElasticSearch terms aggregation

Tags: elasticsearch

Indexed documents are like:

```
{
  id: 1, 
  title: 'Blah',
  ...
  platform: {id: 84, url: 'http://facebook.com', title: 'Facebook'}
  ...
}
```

What I want is count and output stats-by-platform.
For counting, I can use terms aggregation with `platform.id` as a field to count:

```
aggs: {
  platforms: {
    terms: {field: 'platform.id'}
  }
}
```

This way I receive stats as a multiple buckets looking like `{key: 8, doc_count: 162511}`, as expected.

Now, can I somehow add to those buckets also `platform.name` and `platform.url` (for pretty output of stats)? The best I've came with looks like:

```
aggs: {
  platforms: {
    terms: {field: 'platform.id'},
    aggs: {
      name: {terms: {field: 'platform.name'}},
      url: {terms: {field: 'platform.url'}}
    }
  }
}
```

Which, in fact, works, and returns pretty complicated structure in each bucket:

```
{key: 7,
  doc_count: 528568,
  url:
   {doc_count_error_upper_bound: 0,
    sum_other_doc_count: 0,
    buckets: [{key: "http://facebook.com", doc_count: 528568}]},
  name:
   {doc_count_error_upper_bound: 0,
    sum_other_doc_count: 0,
    buckets: [{key: "Facebook", doc_count: 528568}]}},
```

Of course, name and url of platform could be extracted from this structure (like `bucket.url.buckets.first.key`), but is there more clean and simple way to do the task?

Comment: have you found any solution to your problem? I am facing the same right now :(

Comment: I posted it below as my own "accepted" answer :)

Answer (score 72, accepted):

It seems the best way to show intentions is [top hits](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-top-hits-aggregation.html) aggregation: "from each aggregated group select only one document", and then extract platform from it:

```
aggs: {
  platforms: {
    terms: {field: 'platform.id'},
    aggs: {
      platform: {top_hits: {size: 1, _source: {include: ['platform']}}}
  }
}
```

This way, each bucked will look like:

```
{"key": 7,
  "doc_count": 529939,
  "platform": {
    "hits": {
      "hits": [{
       "_source": {
        "platform": 
          {"id": 7, "name": "Facebook", "url": "http://facebook.com"}
        }
      }]
    }
  },
}
```

Which is kinda too deeep (as usual with ES), but clean: `bucket.platform.hits.hits.first._source.platform`

Comment: @moeinrahimi not the whole document, but a subset containing a single entry corresponding to the key `platform`

Answer (score 3):

If you don't necessarily need to get the value of `platform.id`, you could get away with a single aggregation instead using a `script` that concatenates the two fields `name` and `url`:

```
aggs: {
  platforms: {
    terms: {script: 'doc["platform.name"].value + "," + doc["platform.url"].value'}
  }
}
```

Comment: Yep, solution with `script` is pretty obvious. And also pretty ugly, as for me. Just checking if there can be something cleaner.

Comment: Pretty sure something can be done around the [scripted metric](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-scripted-metric-aggregation.html) aggregation. I'll try it out later, but you can give it a shot.